# Weka setDataset(), do I need to use a full data set

Tags: weka

Do I need to use my full training data set, or can I use a data set with only the attribute descriptions built from an arff file with the exact same attributes and say one instance?

I am using a classifier on an EC2 instance so I don't want to have the entire data-set on the EC2 instance as it is very large and grows.

Dose weka require the entire data-set or only the description from the arff file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setDataset() method only takes the attribute descriptions for your Instance from the Instances object (your dataset) that you have defined previously. Therefore it does not matter how large the dataset to which you are referring via the setDataset() method is.